# Dynamically Setting Capacity of a Tank (Fluid source)

Tags: anylogic

So, I have a tank from the fluid source library, which I am using to represent a battery of a vehicle. I would like to dynamically adjust the battery power (i.e the capacity of the tank) dynamically, however, I cannot do that since It must be a static value (at least thats the error I get). Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can tackle this problem?

Thank you

I have tried battery.setcapacity() but this does not work. The only solution I see is switching to system dynamics which would make the problem slightly more difficult only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to literally "fill" it with fluid via an upstream FluiSource. Create that and link it into the tank. Then, you can call `myFluidSource.inject(someAmount)` and it will create that fluid, which will then flow into the tank.

You need to think and apply the library like a fluid (i.e. you cannot just "invent" fluid into a tank, it has to come from some "tap")